# Trouble understanding Poisson Brackets

Tags: partial-derivative, mathematical-physics, classical-mechanics

I'm looking at page 94 [here](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/dynamics/four.pdf) - I understand the definition of Poisson brackets at the top of the page (which uses summation convention) but I don't get why the calculations in (4.61) are true. I'm substituting in the generalised coordinate $q_i$ as $f$ and the generalised momentum $p_i$ as $g$, but I must be doing something wrong - do the subscripts in (4.61) not correspond to the subscripts in the definition?

Comment: What is $q_i$? In the link you provided, authors claim $\{q_i, q_j\}=0$, where are $q_i, q_j$ defined?

Comment: $q_i$ for $i=1,...,n$ are the generalised coordinates used in the Lagrangian/Hamiltonian formulations

Comment: That's not much of a definition. Are they solutions to some differential equation or something like that?

Comment: You need to use the Hamiltonian equation.

Comment: @5xum: It's part of the generic framework which goes: Suppose we have _some_ abstract space $X$ of states parameterized by $q_1,q_2,\ldots,q_n$. Then the operands to the Poisson bracket are functions $X\times Y\times \mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, and the notation $q_i$ is abused to also mean the function that simply returns the $i$'th coordinate of its $X$ input.

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling to see how else to define them. $(q,p)=(q_1,...,q_n,p_1,...p_n)$ is a point in a 2n-dimensional phase space, the Poisson bracket works on functions defined on this phase space. I'm wondering about the specific case when these functions are taken to be $q_i$, $q_j$ etc.

Comment: @user40276 could you please be clearer? I'm looking at Hamilton's equations and I don't see how they could fit in anywhere.

Comment: Sorry, I confused the index. Actually 4.61 is easier, just substitute in the equation. $\partial_{q_j} q_i = \delta_{ij}$ and the same for the $p_i$'s

Comment: So in the first example I'd have $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial{q_i}}{\partial{q_i}}\frac{\partial{q_j}}{\partial{p_i}} - \frac{\partial{q_i}}{\partial{p_i}}\frac{\partial{q_j}}{\partial{q_i}} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} \frac{\partial{q_j}}{\partial{p_i}} - \frac{\partial{q_i}}{\partial{p_j}} \delta_{ij}$
- how is this equal to zero?

Comment: @user40276 Am I getting my indices wrong? Are the i's in (4.61) different from the i's being summed over in the definition? Edit: actually that still doesn't help - if I use indices a,b in (4.61) and plug this into the definition and sum over i, I still can't get zero

Comment: $\partial_{p_i} q_j = 0$. One coordinate is independent of the other ones.

Comment: @user40276 About 5 lines from the bottom on the first page it's written $p_i=p_i(q_j,\dot{q_j},t)$ - so do we abandon this dependence in moving from the Lagrangian to Hamiltonian formalism?

Comment: Not exactly. I never understood exactly how physicists usually treat this. My point of view is that $(q_1, …, q_n, p_1, …, p_n)$ are local coordinates in a manifold for a fixed given time. As time goes on, the manifold is deformed into a new one for each instant of time. So for a fixed time, there is no dependence (except the constraint already determined by the manifold itself).

Answer (score 0):

$\{q_i,q_j\}=\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial q_j}{\partial p_k} - \frac{\partial q_j}{\partial q_k}\frac{\partial q_i}{\partial p_k}=\delta_{ik}\cdot 0 - \delta_{jk}\cdot 0=0$